# LogLogPlot doesn't give log-log scale in both axises

Tags: logarithmic-scale

I have a function called $sol[x]$. I want to plot it in LogLog SCALE. I write:

```
LogLogPlot[sol[x], {x, 1, 500}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

but y-axis of the output in not in logarithmic scale. What should I do?

Comment: If the y-range is not very large, it might look like a linear scale, e.g., `LogLogPlot[1 + x/100, {x, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing because you haven't provided complete info.

```
sol[x_] := x;

LogLogPlot[sol[x], {x, 1, 500}]
```

[image]

Both axis are not in the scientific format ($10^{n}$). If thats what you are looking for then,

```
LogLogPlot[sol[x], {x, 1, 500}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{10^n, 10^Defer[Evaluate[n]]}, {n, 0, 5}], 
   Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {n, 0, 5}]}]
```

[image]